# NL locale returns ambiguous number

Tags: java, locale, number-formatting

if I want to use different number formats across Europe to one format (double), it doesn't seem to work.

```
Locale locale = new Locale("nl", "NL");
NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
returns nf.parse("4,000.00").doubleValue();
```

it returns 4.000 instead of 4000.0, but when enter `nf.parse("900,00")` it works (returns 900.0)
Another time I enter 4000 and it converts to 4000.0 (expected).
So now I am left with inconsistent types.
I want to convert each number to the same double format. can you guide me?

Comment: Since you are talking about locales: in which locale do you print the numbers for yourself? If you calculate 1/2, is the result 0.5 or 0,5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> now I am left with inconsistent types

This is incorrect. The behaviour is entirely consistent and according to spec.

In dutch, the comma is the wholes/fractions separator: There can be only one, and everything to the left is the wholes, and to the right of it, the fractional part. The dot is the thousands separator.

> `900,00`

This is parsed as nine hundred, whole. 900 is to the left of the comma - so those are the wholes. 00 is the fractional part, which is nothing, so, you end up with 900. As expected - a dutch person reading `900,00` would assume that said 'nine hundred'.

> `4000`

Obviously, that's four thousand. No problems there.

> `4,000.00`

That's `4,000` - i.e. four, with `000` as fractional part, and **that is how this is parsed**. The `.00` isn't parsed at all.

### Wait, what?

NumberFormat is designed to parse multiple numbers from a stream of text. Even the `.parse(string)` version of it. Here, try it:

```
Locale locale = new Locale("nl", "NL");
NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
System.out.println(nf.parse("4,000hey now this is strange").doubleValue();
```

works and runs fine, and prints '4'.

### Fixing it

If you really want to fix it, you have a few strategies. One of them, is to first verify that the entire input is valid (e.g. with a regular expression) and only then parsing it.

Another option is to explicitly check that the whole input is consumed. You can do that:

```
String input = "4,000.00";
ParsePosition ps = new ParsePosition(0);

Locale locale = new Locale("nl", "NL");
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(locale);
double v = nf.parse(input, ps).doubleValue();
if (ps.getIndex() != input.length()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Not a number: " + input);
```

The above code parses `900,00` as nine hundred, parser `4000` as four thousand, same for `4.000`, and throws an exception if you attempt to toss `4,000.00` at it. Which is, indeed, not a valid anything in dutch locale.

### I want something that parses both 4,000.00 as 4000, but also 900,00 as 900.

That is highly inconsistent and implies you want `4,000` to be parsed as `4` and yet `4,000.00` as `4000`. If you want this, you're on your own and have to write it from scratch, no built in library (or, as far as I know, any external one) would do such utter befuddled inconsistent craziness.

NB: Note that the snippet would parse `4.000.00` as `400000` and works fine; inconsistent application of thousands separators is leniently parsed by NumberFormat and you can't tell it to be strict. In fact, `4.1.23.4567` is parsed as 41234567 - the only reason `4,000.00` is not parsed in the first place is because dots are not allowed in the fractional part at all. If you don't want that, you're again stuck, you can't use `NumberFormat` then. Regexes maybe, but you're now on the hook for writing one for each locale you care to support.